# optimising sql queries on tables without rowid or primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a db that has a table which does not have a rowid or a primary key. It simply has two columns timestamp and value. both values are double. timestamp is sorted in ascending order.

Is there a way to tell sqlite that timestamp is sorted so that it does binary search for timestamp queries? if not is there a way to simply get the row index of a query result and query using the row index for a speedup?

Comment: Note that a table has no order even if it looks like it does when you view it, the only way to get an order is to use ORDER BY with a SELECT.   Sounds like you need to [add an index](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index) to your timestamp column.

Comment: @AlexK. thank you very much i was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: To be pendantic, you *can't* have a table like that. [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) tables must have a primary key, and all other tables have a rowid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering.

SQL provides indexes, which generally behave exactly as you describe.  So, you want:

```
create index idx_t_timestamp_value on t(timestamp, value);
```

This query will be optimal for `where` clauses such as:

```
where t.timestamp = ?
```

Note that the index is used automatically.  Also, it occupied *additional* storage space (if that happens to be an issue).

Comment: Thank you very much i was hoping there was a better way